# username,email or phone number login system in php

Tags: php

I want to build login system in PHP if user input username or email or phone number and password then user login successful

field username email and password in the wp_users table

and phone number is wp_metauser table
if user enter phone number then match `meta_key= phone_no` and `meta_value=674637388273`

```
     field        value           comments                table
OR   email       =674637388273                            wp_users 
OR   username    =674637388273                            wp_users 
OR   meta_value  =674637388273   if phone no then         wp_metauser 
And  meta_value  = 'phone_no'     //is string             wp_metauser 
AND  Password    =********                                 wp_users
```

I have a query but show error

```
 $query = "select * from  wp_users where ( user_login='$email' OR user_email = '$email' OR 'select * from  wp_usermeta where meta_key='phone_no' and meta_value='$email'') and user_pass='$password'";
```

Comment: You should tell us what the error is. At a glance `'$email''` is wrong. You should also read up on table joins.

Answer (score 1):

Query you you have written is wrong.

Because you cannot have select in where clause.

try using this instead.

```
select a.* 
from  wp_users a
join wp_usermeta b
where (a.user_login='$email' OR a.user_email = '$email' OR (b.meta_key='phone_no' and b.meta_value='$email')) and a.user_pass='$password';
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly see the example of inner join in [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```